# Want to use Whisper in Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I want to use the Whisper in Twilio Studio,
is this possible??

Now I using only Twilio Studio and TwiML Bin

my goal is...

1. User calls to my Twilio number
2. Connect call to the support team phone.
3. After starting the calls between the User(client) & the support team, I want to [Say] a message to the support team then start the calls.

How can I do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Currently you cannot do a whisper with Studio. You could achieve this flow with just TwiML Bins though.

You would need two bins. One to read the message that you want in the whisper and the other two forward the call and point to the whisper.

So, the whisper bin would include TwiML using either [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) or [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) for the message, like this:

```
<Response>
  <Say voice="alice">You are getting a call on the support line, the next voice you will hear is the customer.</Say>
</Response>
```

Then, the bin that responds to the incoming call needs to use [`<Dial>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial) with a [`<Number>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number). The `<Number>` `url` attribute should point at the TwiML above for the whisper. Like:

```
<Response>
  <Dial>
    <Number url="TWIML_BIN_URL">+123456789</Number>
  </Dial>
</Response>
```

Comment: any plans to add whisper support to studio?

Comment: nevermind you have to choose add TwiML Redirect and put the URL for it from the BIN, so it works fine :)